# How to stop the error occuring in my Python curses code?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, curses

I'm confused about why this error keeps popping up whenever I run some curses code.

Code:

```
import curses

stdscr = initscr()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abd-ur-Rahmaan\Desktop\Abd-Ur-Rahmaan Shabbir\Python coding\Python Advanced Shit\The first curses project\The first curses project.py", line 3, in <module>
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
  File "C:\Users\Abd-ur-Rahmaan\Desktop\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module. A ported version called UniCurses is available. You could also try the Console module written by Fredrik Lundh, which doesn’t use the same API as curses but provides cursor-addressable text output and full support for mouse and keyboard input.

Refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: does not work, tried it out installed it and everything and i still get the same error

Comment: dont worry about it, i figured it out, thanks for helping anyway

Answer (score 0):

put your .py file wherever you have PATH enabled (it should be the python folder as standart)

pip install windows-curses

right click on start > run

enter the name of the file (snake.py for example)

run